# Can a website recognize my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ip

There is an adult live chat website that keeps banning every new account I create using my same labtop, I don't know how they can recognize my labtop. Anyone has any idea? I am curious to know even if I don't want to use that website anymore.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since changing your IP didn't work, there might be cookies that are identifying you. Try clearing them out.

Comment: This is a radical idea, you could try *not* doing whatever behaviour it is that is getting you banned.

Answer (score 5):

[Browser fingerprinting](https://pixelprivacy.com/resources/browser-fingerprinting/) is probably the reason.  Your browser, your fonts, your screen size, browser extensions, and much, much more, can uniquely identify an individual.  Even more so than an IP address, which are known to change, or be hidden.

Comment: I think chrome has an extension to thwart fingerprinting.

Comment: @Moab I use EFF's Privacy Badger, but other than using Tor, I dont believe there is much you can do to stop it.